# Rendering angular page fails on deployment with travis

Tags: angular, travis-ci

I'm deploying an angular web application using travis and encounter following errors. The build runs fine, where as I'm encountering issues while rendering the content. i.e The `ng build --prod` command runs fine. However whenever I try to visit the application from a browser, I get an empty page with following error messages in console. However, if I build and deploy the same angular app from my own machine the application works as expected.

```
main.ab3e11a36e446f1405c1.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property '__source' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property '__source' of undefined
    at t.get (main.ab3e11a36e446f1405c1.js:1)
    at cg (main.ab3e11a36e446f1405c1.js:1)
    at t.get (main.ab3e11a36e446f1405c1.js:1)
    at je (main.ab3e11a36e446f1405c1.js:1)
    at Te (main.ab3e11a36e446f1405c1.js:1)
    at Ie (main.ab3e11a36e446f1405c1.js:1)
    at main.ab3e11a36e446f1405c1.js:1
    at main.ab3e11a36e446f1405c1.js:1
    at hg (main.ab3e11a36e446f1405c1.js:1)
    at cg (main.ab3e11a36e446f1405c1.js:1)
    at P (polyfills.8a08c7bebefd1a5e8a0e.js:1)
    at P (polyfills.8a08c7bebefd1a5e8a0e.js:1)
    at polyfills.8a08c7bebefd1a5e8a0e.js:1
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.8a08c7bebefd1a5e8a0e.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.ab3e11a36e446f1405c1.js:1)
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.8a08c7bebefd1a5e8a0e.js:1)
    at t.runTask (polyfills.8a08c7bebefd1a5e8a0e.js:1)
    at g (polyfills.8a08c7bebefd1a5e8a0e.js:1)
Cp @ main.ab3e11a36e446f1405c1.js:1
t.handleError @ main.ab3e11a36e446f1405c1.js:1
next @ main.ab3e11a36e446f1405c1.js:1
o @ main.ab3e11a36e446f1405c1.js:1
e.__tryOrUnsub @ main.ab3e11a36e446f1405c1.js:1
e.next @ main.ab3e11a36e446f1405c1.js:1
e._next @ main.ab3e11a36e446f1405c1.js:1
e.next @ main.ab3e11a36e446f1405c1.js:1
e.next @ main.ab3e11a36e446f1405c1.js:1
e.emit @ main.ab3e11a36e446f1405c1.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.ab3e11a36e446f1405c1.js:1
e.invoke @ polyfills.8a08c7bebefd1a5e8a0e.js:1
t.run @ polyfills.8a08c7bebefd1a5e8a0e.js:1
t.runOutsideAngular @ main.ab3e11a36e446f1405c1.js:1
onHandleError @ main.ab3e11a36e446f1405c1.js:1
e.handleError @ polyfills.8a08c7bebefd1a5e8a0e.js:1
t.runGuarded @ polyfills.8a08c7bebefd1a5e8a0e.js:1
e @ polyfills.8a08c7bebefd1a5e8a0e.js:1
r.microtaskDrainDone @ polyfills.8a08c7bebefd1a5e8a0e.js:1
g @ polyfills.8a08c7bebefd1a5e8a0e.js:1
Promise.then (async)
v @ polyfills.8a08c7bebefd1a5e8a0e.js:1
e.scheduleTask @ polyfills.8a08c7bebefd1a5e8a0e.js:1
onScheduleTask @ polyfills.8a08c7bebefd1a5e8a0e.js:1
e.scheduleTask @ polyfills.8a08c7bebefd1a5e8a0e.js:1
t.scheduleTask @ polyfills.8a08c7bebefd1a5e8a0e.js:1
t.scheduleMicroTask @ polyfills.8a08c7bebefd1a5e8a0e.js:1
I @ polyfills.8a08c7bebefd1a5e8a0e.js:1
P @ polyfills.8a08c7bebefd1a5e8a0e.js:1
(anonymous) @ polyfills.8a08c7bebefd1a5e8a0e.js:1
r @ runtime.772503e10c93ab63efc3.js:1
(anonymous) @ 2.2a8b5bc9585032a33c70.js:1
```

Travisfile

```
sudo: required
addons:
  ssh_known_hosts:
  - staging.com
  - production.com
language: node_js
node_js:
- '8'
before_script:
- nvm use 8.9.1
- npm install npm@latest -g
- npm install
script:
- ng build --prod
before_install:
- openssl aes-256-cbc -in ./deploy/deploy_rsa.enc -out ./deploy/deploy_rsa -d
- chmod 400 ./deploy/deploy_rsa
deploy:
- provider: script
  skip_cleanup: true
  script: bash ./deploy/deploy-qa.sh
  on:
    branch: develop
- provider: script
  skip_cleanup: true
  script: bash ./deploy/deploy-prod.sh
  on:
    branch: master
    tags: true
notifications:
  email: false
cache:
  npm: true
```

Deployment Script Contains

```
 #!/usr/bin/env bash
 rsync -av -e "ssh -i ./deploy/deploy_rsa" ./dist/frontend/ ubuntu@staging.com:~/frontend
 ssh -i ./deploy/deploy_rsa ubuntu@staging.com "sudo rm -rf /var/www/frontend.cf/*"
 ssh -i ./deploy/deploy_rsa ubuntu@staging.com "sudo cp -r /home/ubuntu/frontend/* /var/www/frontend.cf/"
 ssh -i ./deploy/deploy_rsa ubuntu@staging.com "sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/frontend.cf/*"
 ssh -i ./deploy/deploy_rsa ubuntu@staging.com "sudo rm -fr /home/ubuntu/frontend"
```

I tried to debug the travis build and run the deployment script, the deployment succeeds but again the page fails to load.

Comment: Best guess: Your deployment script is leaving out one or more required files.

Comment: Thanks @AlexWeavers, I just removed --prod flag and the deployment works for the staging server. However, this means that Angular will run in development mode and is not suitable for production server. 
I run exactly the same commands from my local machine and it works fine. I don't get what is being missed here.